# How to get a part of string which separated by forward slash in Javascript Regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have a string something like this **1006 / HKD-undefined-000002** format and I also need both of it part sometime I need the right and then left one.
But I dont know how to call in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `RegEx`, a little `split()` method should work:

```
var str = '1006 / HKD-undefined-000002';
if(str.indexOf('/') > -1) {
  var parts = str.split('/');
  var firPart = parts[0];
  var secPart = parts[1];
} else {
  console.log('No forward slash');
}
```